How do I upgrade the Gradle Plugin while using external React Native-package?
Working on a project that uses the "@react-native/gradle-plugin"-package. In Android Studio it recommends that i upgrade the Gradle plugin, currently on 7.4.2 but using a later version of Gradle and therefore need to upgrade the Gradle Plugin.
But the problem is that in my build.gradle-file the version dependency looks like this: classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle"), not specifying the version of the plugin i am using. I understand that this is because of the usage of the package, and as a result i cant use the Upgrade Assistant in Android Studio.
So the question is: How do i upgrade the Gradle Plugin when using the @react-native/gradle-plugin"-package?
Tried putting the Gradle-plugin version after "com.android.tools.build:gradle:xxx", like it should when not using the external package, but it didnt work.

Turned out I just needed to upgrade the version for @react-native/gradle-plugin" in package.json and reinstall the package. Made it harder for me than it really was
